# Use for loop to update existing variables from combining string

Tags: loops, variables

I have a variable I use on a global scope. But I use functions I built in a class to update them and display them.

I have a variable called `enemy_1_health` that pulls his info from a dictionary. And it does this for each of his stats.

```
Bat = {'hp'{1:6,2:7,3:8},{'Mp'{1:8,2:9,3:10}
```

etc for each level and  'str', 'dex', etc..

I'm trying to use a for loop to cycle through each iteration and store it in a variable depending on the room. Each room has different monsters and each monster had there own stats.

I don't want to type:

```
Enemy_1_heath = BAT['Health'][enemy_1_level]
```

I've created dictionary for BAT

```
MONSTER_NAMES = [BAT,  BLOB, HAWK,  ETC]
STAT_NAMES =['health', 'magic', 'str', etc]
```

So now it looks like this:

```
Enemy_1_health = MONSTOR_NAMES[0]STATS[0][enemy_1_level]

ENEMY_NUMBER = 1

I did something like 'Enemy_' +  str(ENEMY_NUMBER) + '_' + STAT_NAMES[0]
```

To change the name of the variable to match the global variable that already exist. I want it to override it. But it's not changing the global variable as it's recognized as a string variable and not the actual variable name.

I want to be able to change the enemy that I'm loading. Is it enemy 1, 2 or 3? They are each different.

Right now I'm loading each Stat in individually for all 3 enemies.  I'd rather write a for loop that cycles through all the iterations of the dictionaries depending on what I set the variables to. Room 1 enemy 2.

And the code works for all future monsters that I decide to load in.

Any help is appreciated.  I've been looking at vars and globals and exec functions but I can't seem to figure it out not sure if I'm googling the correct terms to get the desired results.

Comment: How about adding a language tag?